# Dynamically building array, appending values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a bunch of `options` in this `select`, each with `value`s like:

```
context|cow
context|test
thing|1
thing|5
thing|27
context|beans
```

while looping through the options, I want to build an array that checks to see if keys exist, and if they don't they make the key then append the value. then the next loop through, if the key exists, add the next value, comma separated.

the ideal output would be:

```
arr['context'] = 'cow,test,beans';
arr['thing'] = '1,5,27';
```

here's what i have so far, but this isn't a good strategy to build the values..

```
function sift(select) {
        vals = [];
        $.each(select.options, function() {
            var valArr = this.value.split('|');
            var key = valArr[0];
            var val = valArr[1];
            if (typeof vals[key] === 'undefined') {
                vals[key] = []; 
            }
            vals[key].push(val);
        });
        console.log(vals);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, ultimately? My instinct is that there's a better way.

Comment: @mblase75 good point, I usually state this looks like an XY Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing code works by changing

```
 vals=[];
```

To

```
 vals={};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrxuM/

Answer (score 1):

```
function sift(select) {
    var vals = {};//notice I made an object, not an array, this is to create an associative array
    $.each(select.options, function() {
        var valArr = this.value.split('|');
        if (typeof vals[valArr[0]] === 'undefined') {
            vals[valArr[0]] = ''; 
        } else {
            vals[valArr[0]] += ',';
        }
        vals[valArr[0]] += valArr[1];
    });
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/xtfm2/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about an extensible, reusable, encapsulated solution:

```
function MyOptions()
{
  var _optionNames = [];
  var _optionValues = [];
  function _add(name, value)
  {
    var nameIndex = _optionNames.indexOf(name);
    if (nameIndex < 0)
    {
      _optionNames.push(name);
      var newValues = [];
      newValues.push(value);
      _optionValues.push(newValues); 
    }
    else
    {
      var values = _optionValues[nameIndex];
      values.push(value);
      _optionValues[nameIndex] = values;
    }
  };
  function _values(name)
  {
    var nameIndex = _optionNames.indexOf(name);
    if (nameIndex < 0)
    {
      return [];
    }
    else
    {
      return _optionValues[nameIndex];
    }
  };
  var public = 
  {
    add: _add,
    values: _values
  };

  return public;
}
```

usage:

```
var myOptions = MyOptions();
myOptions.add("context", "cow");
myOptions.add("context","test");    
myOptions.add("thing","1");    
myOptions.add("thing","5");    
myOptions.add("thing","27");    
myOptions.add("context","beans");    

console.log(myOptions.values("context").join(","));
console.log(myOptions.values("thing").join(","));
```

working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zjamy/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works, but if someone could optimize it, I'd love to see.

```
function updateSiftUrl(select) { var
    vals = {};
    $.each(select.options, function() {
        var valArr = this.value.split('|');
        var key = valArr[0];
        var val = valArr[1];
        if (typeof vals[key] === 'undefined') {
            vals[key] = val;    
            return;
        }
        vals[key] = vals[key] +','+ val;
    });
    console.log(vals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
$("select#yourselect").change(function(){
    var optionArray =
        $(":selected", $(this)).map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(", ");
});
```

If you've selected 3 options, `optionArray` should contain something like `option1, option2, option3`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you don't want `vals[key]` to be an array - you want it to be a string. so try doing

```
        if (typeof vals[key] === 'undefined') {
            vals[key] = '; 
        }
        vals[key] = vals[key] + ',' + val;
```